# How to treat obsolete questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm just reviewing [How does VARIABLE=() { function definition } work in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152831/how-does-variable-function-definition-work-in-bash). It was posted before the [shellshock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shellshock) vulnerability. Neither the question, nor the answer, nor any comment in the whole thread mentions anything about Shellshock. There's also no Bash version mentioned anywhere. So in today's reality this Q&A is out of space. Still, historically it's valuable. Now, the question is what to do with such threads?

1. Answer it with state of the art details and with a background in history.
2. Update the question and include the history.
3. Just comment under the question.
4. Mark it somehow - how? A special tag? Title edit?
5. Close it with appropriate radio button option - this would be a feature request to SE I guess.
6. Something still different. What?

Comment: I'd go for the first option if I felt strongly about it. In the past I have also left comments on the accepted answers when I felt that this was enough.

Answer (score 2):

I went for #2 and edited the question adding to it this warning at the top:

> WARNING - this question is about the Bash before the shellshock
>   vulnerability, due to which it was changed.

Here's the question again: [How does VARIABLE=() { function definition } work in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152831/how-does-variable-function-definition-work-in-bash)

Comment: I think this was a good compromise.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct would be #3 -- leave a comment under the question, if anything. Stack Exchange posts are timestamped, so visitors could determine the timeline of the question, answers, and the [Shellshock timeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157381/117549) to see what's relevant.